# Random Image on Page Load (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, plugins

I found this great plugin that pulls random images and display it in a div.

Se author link,

http://www.robwalshonline.com/posts/jquery-plugin-random-image-on-page-load/

I tried to use it in a wordpress site, but when the image loads it is only shows the file-name
and not the picture...  Se link (I put a ugly blue box just to show where the image should show up
on page loads. The script only activated on index page.)

http://libra-frisk.com/toveAlsterdal/

How can I solve that?

Comment: I am getting 404 for this image that you are trying to load in blue box. http://libra-frisk.com/toveAlsterdal/images/flyer.jpg

Comment: Look at the source - the image doesn't exist at the URL you're trying to load (I got `images/flyer.jpg`).  That relative path doesn't even exist.

Comment: There is no such image on server, http://libra-frisk.com/toveAlsterdal/images/flyer.jpg returns http 404

Comment: The full path to the image, http://libra-frisk.com/toveAlsterdal/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/flyer.jpg

Comment: Did you place images in download folder and included download folder path into SRC value of Images?

Comment: @wpdesign you must correct the path of the image and then see what happens.

Comment: How do i declare th path in the plugin? path: 'images/'

Answer (score 0):

The URI for the image is wrong. Thats why you only see the alt-text.
Make sure the image is in the /images directory.

Comment: Solved thanx for your help people!